Finding a common answer in a problem solved using the Dirac Delta function
Let $n_{t}$ be standard white Gaussian noise, $\xi_{t}=\int_{0}^{t}n_{s}ds$. Find the mathematical expectation, variance and correlation function of the random process $\xi_{t}$.
Additional information about standard white Gaussian noise that we know: $En_{t}=0$, $K_{n}(t;s)=c\delta(t-s)$, $S_{n}(t;s)=\frac{1}{2\pi}$.
My solution:
$K_{\xi}(t;s)=cov(\xi_{t};\xi_{s})=\int_{0}^{s}\int_{0}^{t}c\delta(\bar{t}-\bar{s})d\bar{t}d\bar{s}=|u=\bar{t}-\bar{s},du=d\bar{t},0\rightarrow-\bar{s},t\rightarrow t-\bar{s}|=c\int_{0}^{s}\int_{-\bar{s}}^{t-\bar{s}}\delta(u)dud\bar{s}=c\int_{0}^{s}(H(t-\bar{s})-H(-\bar{s}))d\bar{s}=|k1=t-\bar{s},dk1=-d\bar{s},0\rightarrow t,s\rightarrow t-s;k2=-\bar{s},dk2=-d\bar{s},0\rightarrow0,s\rightarrow-s|=-c(\int_{t}^{t-s}H(k1)dk1-\int_{0}^{-s}H(k2)dk2)=-c(I1-I2)=I$
$I1=\int_{t}^{t-s}H(k1)dk1=
\begin{cases}
0,t\leqslant0\\
-t,t>0,t-s\leqslant0\\
-s,t>0,t-s>0\\
\end{cases}=
\begin{cases}
0,t\leqslant0\\
-t,0<t\leqslant s\\
-s,t>0,t>s\\
\end{cases}$
$I2=\int_{0}^{-s}H(k2)dk2=
\begin{cases}
0,-s\leqslant0\\
-s,-s>0\\
\end{cases}=
\begin{cases}
0,s\geqslant0\\
-s,s<0\\
\end{cases}$
How do we now combine $I1$, $I2$ to get the overall answer?
